# Multiple Doxygen Config Files

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to include multiple doxygen config files in one config file?

Let's say you had ~15 different doxygen config files spread across multiple repositories. Let's also say that you were pulling in multiple source files from different repositories into one folder. If each different config file has slightly different settings, then you wouldn't be able to generate documentation by just randomly picking one of the config files.

Can you include multiple different config files or would you have to create one amalgamated master doxygen config that combines all the settings from each different config file?

Comment: How will you handle the case when two config files has the same option set to different value? How to decide which one to use. In my opinion it is better to have special config.

Comment: As A.Albershteyn already mentioned the problem will be the different set configuration options. In case it is necessary to have different options for different source files the only possibility I see is to build the parts for each different configuration file including generating  tag files (GENERATE_TAGFILE) and use these tag files with the other projects (you will have to run doxygen twice , first to generate the tag files and subsequently using the tag files).